# Accessing Tax Codes in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: odoo

I have just installed OpenERP 7.0, added two companies in it, I have installed the Accounting module, I can access:
Accounting ‣ Configuration ‣ Taxes ‣ Taxes

But I can't find Taxes Codes in Taxes menu:
Accounting ‣ Configuration ‣ Taxes ‣ Tax Codes

So, I can't see where to associate a tax to a company.

Can someone help me about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to user configuration and give proper rights (accounting manager ) in you case and then go to accounting configuration menu. You'll find menu for tax.
.